# How to use Google Drive advanced search to find files that are not shared?

Tags: google-drive

I'm trying to find files in Google Drive that are:

1. Owned by me
2. Located in "My Files" (not shared folders or Team Drives)
3. Not shared with anyone

The advanced search dropdown has options for 1 and 2, but I can't figure out the "Not shared with anyone" piece.

The [Google Drive advanced search documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) has options like `to:` to find files that are shared with specific people, e.g. `to: notme@example.com`. But, I need the opposite of this, something like `-(is:shared)`.

As an experiment, I tried to search files that are "owned by me" and "not shared with a specific person" by using the `-` and `to:` options:

`owner:me -to:notme@example.com`

This simply returned the message "None of your files or folders matched this search", which makes me think you can't use `-` and `to:` together.

#### Manual workaround

My current workaround is to use `owner:me` and search in "My Files" and manually scan the files that do not have the "shared" icon to the right of the filename, but I would love to find a way to filter all these files using advanced search.

Comment: It is a pain when the files are shared with someone and you are trying to find files not yet shared with a specific person!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, put the email addy in parenthesis:
owner:me -to:(xxx@gmail.com)
This works too:
((owner:me) AND (-to:(xxx@gmail.com))

However, it did NOT work when I tried to add the "parent:" variable to search in a specific folder, in only worked in My Drive no matter where in the string that variable was, or if I used the AND configuration.

Comment: It seems that if I put the word "AND", it searchs only documents where the AND word is included.
But putting everything between brackets is a nice hint.